# Pyinstaller in ubuntu16.04 :Python library not found: libpython3.6mu.so.1.0, libpython3.6m.so.1.0, libpython3.6.so.1.0

Tags: python, python3

1. I want to use pyinstaller make a bundle in ubuntu 16.04. the python env is created by conda which python=3.6.8.
2. When i run pyinstaller, below error occour. I know ubuntu16.04 has python3.5 why python3.6-dev can not install?

   ```
   27087 INFO: Looking for eggs
   27087 INFO: Python library not in binary dependencies. Doing additional searching...
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "/home/bibao/miniconda3/envs/labelmecs_pack_server/bin/pyinstaller", line 10, in <module>
       sys.exit(run())
     File "/home/bibao/miniconda3/envs/labelmecs_pack_server/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 111, in run
       run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
     File "/home/bibao/miniconda3/envs/labelmecs_pack_server/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 63, in run_build
       PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
     File "/home/bibao/miniconda3/envs/labelmecs_pack_server/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 838, in main
       build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
     File "/home/bibao/miniconda3/envs/labelmecs_pack_server/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 784, in build
       exec(text, spec_namespace)
     File "<string>", line 23, in <module>
     File "/home/bibao/miniconda3/envs/labelmecs_pack_server/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 241, in __init__
       self.__postinit__()
     File "/home/bibao/miniconda3/envs/labelmecs_pack_server/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/datastruct.py", line 158, in __postinit__
       self.assemble()
     File "/home/bibao/miniconda3/envs/labelmecs_pack_server/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 573, in assemble
       self._check_python_library(self.binaries)
     File "/home/bibao/miniconda3/envs/labelmecs_pack_server/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 676, in _check_python_library
       raise IOError(msg)
   OSError: Python library not found: libpython3.6mu.so.1.0, libpython3.6m.so.1.0, libpython3.6.so.1.0
   This would mean your Python installation doesn't come with proper library files.
   This usually happens by missing development package, or unsuitable build parameters of Python installation.

   * On Debian/Ubuntu, you would need to install Python development packages
     * apt-get install python3-dev
     * apt-get install python-dev
   * If you're building Python by yourself, please rebuild your Python with `--enable-shared` (or, `--enable-framework` on Darwin)
   ```

Comment: Did you run: `sudo apt-get install python3-dev python-dev`?

Comment: I run it , but can not install python3.6-dev. It tell me that the python3-dev already is the newest.

Answer (score 0):

Try follow the last line of message:

```
* If you're building Python by yourself, please rebuild your Python with `--enable-shared` (or, `--enable-framework` on Darwin)
```

Clearly, rebuild your Python by `./configure --enable-shared`, and make sure the `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` does include your python3.6/lib path. Say if your python3.6.8 is installed at /home/bibao/python3.6, than use `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/bibao/python3.6/lib` to add PATH.

I do not use conda. but I think you may use `find` to find python path, or just build a python3.6.8 alone for packaging use, even the latter is not elegant enough.

Comment: i do not building Python, i just want to build a application package and the application's program language is python.

Comment: I knew. But before "build a application package", you need rebuild your Python to generate "Python library" includes `libpython3.6mu.so.1.0`, `libpython3.6m.so.1.0`, and `libpython3.6.so.1.0`.